# How can I fix a Makefile error 'unrecognized reference' while linking?

Tags: c++, g++, makefile

I am getting the following while linking:

```
BServer.cpp:(.text+0x58e5): undefined reference to `dbusServer::dbusServer(char*, int)'
BServer.cpp:(.text+0x58f4): undefined reference to `dbusServer::~dbusServer()'
```

The g++ output when running make is:

```
g++ dbusServer.o PCounter.o BServer.o -o PCounter -L./BAPI/lib -L./usr/local/lib/libdbus -lBAPIx64 -m64 -lstdc++ -lpthread -lboost_system -lboost_program_options -L./home/ben/Downloads/libdbus-3.0.3/src/ -ldbus -L/home/ben/workspace/IntegratedPCounter/src/PCounter
```

I am including from `/home/ben/workspace/IntegratedPCounter/src/PCounter` as `'#include "dbusServer.h'` in `BServer.cpp`

I then try to create an instance of `dbusServer` in `BServer`, like this:

```
dbusServer modserver("192.168.0.9",5432);
```

Here is the header file for dbus:

```
// Define the number of devices to be managed
#include <dbus.h>
#define ADDRESS_START    0
#define ADDRESS_END      7

#ifndef dbusSERVER_H_
#define dbusSERVER_H_

class dbusServer {
dbus_t *ctx;
int nb;
typedef struct regHL
{
    uint16_t hibits;
    uint16_t lowbits;
};
private:
    void SplitCount(int); //To-do determine of the value needs to be split
    void addDevice(int);

public:
    dbusServer(char *, int);

    ~dbusServer();

    int WriteDeviceCounts(int, int);
    int AddDevice(int);
    int resetDeviceCounts(int);
 };
 #endif /* dbusSERVER_H_ *
```

Here is the dbus code:

```
#include <dbus.h>;
#include <errno.h>
#include "dbusServer.h"
//Using boost program options to read command line and config file data
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <syslog.h>
using namespace std;

namespace po = boost::program_options;
//alias program option namespace


    int nb = 0;
    dbus_t *ctx;
    int rc;
    int dbusServer::dbusServer(char *IPAddress, int port) {
        nb = 0;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        int socket;
        ctx = dbus_new_tcp(IPAddress, port);
        dbus_mapping_t *mb_mapping;
    mb_mapping = dbus_mapping_new(500, 500, 500, 500);
    if (mb_mapping == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate the mapping: %s\n",
                dbus_strerror(errno));
        dbus_free(ctx);
        return (-1);
    }

    socket = dbus_tcp_listen(ctx, 1);
    dbus_tcp_accept(ctx, &socket);

    return (0);
}

dbusServer::~dbusServer() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
    dbus_mapping_free (mb_mapping);
    dbus_close(ctx);
    dbus_free(ctx);
}

int writeDeviceCounts(uint32_t counts, int device) {
    //split the 32 bit value from the counting device
    uint16_t highBits = (counts & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000) >> 16; // get the high bits
    uint16_t lowBits = (counts & 0xFFFFFFFF); //get the low bits

    return (-1);
}


int addDevice(int device_id) {
    //increment the device counter
    return(-1);

}

void removeDevice(int device_id) {

}



void resetDeviceCounts(int device_id) {

}
```

In the book "Safe C++" (Kushnir, V.,O'Reilly Press, 2012) on p.58, there is an example of bad class creation, especially in regards to coding a descructor. However, the corrected implementation looks like it would solve some of my problems.

One thing I am wondering is how to avoid problems with implementing a class in c++ so these things don't come up. There must be a list of do's and don'ts in the common vernacular that can steer one away from issues.

Comment: dbusServer(char *, int);

    ~dbusServer();  - these are your declarations, do you have a similar implementation in the dbusServer.cpp file?

Comment: Lose the semi-colon after `#include <dbus.h>;`.  Also, since `dbusServer.h` include `dbus.h` itself, it is not clear that you need the `#include <dbus.h>` line in the `.cpp` at all.

Comment: Your code is all over the place:

1. The comment after the `#endif` in your header is not terminated (a copy-paste error?).
2. Your code is not properly indented, making it hard to read.
3. What are those global variables `nb`, `ctx` and `rc` doing in your source `.cpp` file, just before the constructor?
4. A constructor doesn't return anything, remove the `int` in front of it and the `return`!
5. The functions `writeDeviceCounts`, `addDevice` and `removeDevice` need `dbusServer::` to be prefixed.
6. Your spelling of the function names between the header and the source file is inconsistent.

Comment: 3)The global variables were originally in the constructor, but when the destructor is called to dispose of the data, the compiler would complain that the variables were not in scope.  4) I will remove the return in the constructor. Hopefully cleaning up the scrambled code will reveal more about the error. -> Jonathan I think has it figured out...I do not need to include dbus.h since dbusServer.h already has the include; this is confusing me and the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dbusServer.cpp is problematic. remove the lines like `class dbusServer {`, it makes your dbusServer(...) to be referenced as `dbusServer::dbusServer::dbusServer(...)`.

extract your member functions codes from the class definition in .cpp file.

in summary, a class declared in *.h as

```
class dbusServer{
    dbsusServer(char*, int);
    ...
};
```

its implementation in *.cpp should be

```
dbusServer::dbusServer(char*, int){
...
}
```

instead of :

```
class dbusServer{
     dbusServer::dbusServer(char*, int){
      ...
     }
};
```

In addition, the constructor is not right.

```
int dbusServer::dbusServer(char *IPAddress, int port) {
```

it should be:

```
dbusServer::dbusServer(char *IPAddress, int port) {
```

Comment: Ok, I did that ane issues a 'make clean' and I still get :     **BServer.cpp:(.text+0x58e5): undefined reference to `dbusServer::dbusServer(char*, int)'**

Comment: Ok, I still am getting the error.

Comment: the constructor is not well defined.

Answer (score 2):

```
undefined reference to dbusServer::dbusServer(char*, int)
undefined reference to dbusServer::~dbusServer()'
```

Those errors mean that you told the compiler these functions exist...

```
class dbusServer {
    dbusServer(char *, int);
    ~dbusServer();
};
```

...and the compiler decided to use them.

But you never wrote them.  They're undefined.

**Edit:**

In one of your source files, you need to have:

```
dbusServer::dbusServer(char *, int)
{
    // Your code
}

dbusServer::~dbusServer()
{
    // Your code
}
```

Comment: The methods definitely exist in dbsServer.cpp, so that isn't it. In the cpp file, though, I had dbus::dbusServer and dbus::~dbusServer and it said that I had a double reference, so I took out dbus::

Comment: @bentaisan Please add that code to your question.